# Numpy convert scalars to arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am evaluating arbitrary expressions in terms of an x array, such as 3*x**2 + 4. This normally results in an array with x's shape. However if the expression is just a constant, it returns a scalar. What is the best way to ensure it has x's shape without explicitly checking the shape? Multiplying by numpy.ones(x.shape) works, but I think that uses unnecessary computations.

Edit:
To be clear, I don't just want it to be an array with size one, I want it to be the same shape and size as X. 
I'm evaluating a string using NumExpr which can contain an arbitrary function of x:

```
x = numpy.linspace(min, max, num)
y = numexpr.evaluate(expr, {'x': x}, {})
```

I want to get an array of y-values that could be plotted against x through matplotlib. Currently I am doing this, which works fine:

```
y = numpy.ones(x.size) * y
```

But I'm worried that this is wasteful for large sizes. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think I follow what you mean, but you should include minimal, end-to-end code to be clear.

Answer (score 24):

See [atleast_1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html):

> Convert inputs to arrays with at least one dimension.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 42  # x is a scalar
>>> np.atleast_1d(x)
array([42])

>>> x_is_array = np.array(42)  # A zero dim array
>>> np.atleast_1d(x_is_array)
array([42])

>>> x_is_another_array = np.array([42])  # A 1d array
>>> np.atleast_1d(x_is_another_array)
array([42])

>>> np.atleast_1d(np.ones((3, 3)))  # Any other numpy array
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: This was a long time ago, but as I mentioned in the question I wanted the output array to have the same size as the input array. I think I ended up assigning it to a view of a presized array like `out[:] = y`.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm unsure whether x will be a scalar, list/tuple or array, I've been using:

```
x = np.asarray(x).reshape(1, -1)[0,:]
```

Alternatively by (ab)using the broadcasting rules, you could equally write:

```
x = np.asarray(x) * np.ones(1)
```

Perhaps a slightly more streamlined syntax is to make use of the extra arguments on the array constructor:

```
x = np.array(x, ndmin=1, copy=False)
```

Which will ensure that the array has at least one dimension.

But this is one of those things that seems a bit clumsy in numpy

Comment: could you clarify why you suggest using `copy=False`. Would you use it if you know that `x` is a scalar?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reshape: `np.reshape(x, (1,1))`

Here's demonstration:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> a = np.reshape(x, (1,1))
>>> a[0]
array([4])
>>> a[0][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

`lin_reg.predict(np.array(6.5).reshape(1,-1))`

Comment: Please explain your answer and why this should solve the problem.